# Update values of one table from other table

Tags: sql, oracle

For Example I have 2 tables

Table 1:

```
id    number     name
-----------------------
1     1684       abc
2     9666       pqr
3     1234       adf
```

Table 2:

```
id    number     name
-----------------------
1     9109       xyz
2     9564       pqr
```

How do i get output like this?

Table 1:

```
id    number     name
-----------------------
1     9109       xyz
2     9564       pqr
3     1234       adf
```

I want to merge table 2 in table.
Also if the column-"name" value is updated/changed from this merge, I need to update status column and i need to call a procedure of smtp mail, how can i handle this?
The status column has different status transitions(eg: x->y, a->b).
and if the record is not in table1 it should be inserted.

These all operations are inside a procedure used in batch job.

Please advice me with this.
Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: `I need to update status column` Does your table also have `STATUS` column as well. You didnot show in your sample data.

Comment: Yes there is a status column too. There are different transitions for status.For example : 
Pending to Updated, Signed-Off to Updated

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this, say, using MERGE statement, but most simple is

```
Connected to Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 

SQL> create table t$1 ("id" integer, "number" integer, "name" varchar2(3));

Table created

SQL> create table t$2 ("id" integer, "number" integer, "name" varchar2(3));

Table created

SQL> insert into t$1 values (1, 1684, 'abc');

1 row inserted

SQL> insert into t$1 values (2, 9666, 'pqr');

1 row inserted

SQL> insert into t$1 values (3, 1234, 'adf');

1 row inserted

SQL> insert into t$2 values (1, 9109, 'xyz');

1 row inserted

SQL> insert into t$2 values (2, 9564, 'pqr');

1 row inserted

SQL> update t$1 set
  2    ("number", "name") = (select "number", "name" from t$2 where t$2."id" = t$1."id")
  3  where
  4    "id" in (select "id" from t$2);

2 rows updated

SQL> select * from t$1;

      id   number name
-------- -------- --------
       1     9109 xyz
       2     9564 pqr
       3     1234 adf
```

Comment: This is just an example. I wanted to update 66 columns and also check if specific columns are updated i need to do some operations like sending mail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MERGE` to do it very simply:

```
MERGE INTO table1 dst
USING table2 src
ON    ( src.id = dst.id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET number = src.number,
             name   = src.name;
```

Comment: Tried this approach. In WHEN MATCHED , CASE doesnt work. I also want to check if the values are changed of specific columns i need to do some operations

Comment: @ojas360 This is an answer to the question you have asked. If you want to do something that is not in the question then we can't help you with that as you haven't asked it.

Comment: I have stated this in the question description.